# I'd like some direction about developing a multi-platform mobile-app

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

There are so many tools out there for mobile development that it's information overload. I'm a programmer as well and would like some opinions on what would work best for my requirements. I don't own a mac and have no plans on purchasing one if i can help it. The app i'm trying to build seems relatively simple. I also want to have IPhone and Android versions of it, with possibility for Windows phone in the future.

- needs to be a free version with youtube videos  - so access to the youtube player
- i'd like to be able to embed some articles - not sure about this one, either just text or pdf etc.
- needs to have the option to upgrade to a paid version.
- the paid version would be a subscription based service.
- the paid version would be serving video content from S3(or other better sources)
- the paid version needs to have a notification/push service where i can push content to the app on a monthly basis.

So, given all these, i've looked at appcelerator, phonegap, xamarin and lots of other services. They all seem good but given the requirements, i'm starting to lean a little bit towards phonegap as this is not going to be a game and it's a service primarily and it can handle both Iphone and Android as well.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PhoneGap is your best bet, I've spoken to quite a few Mobile Application Development Company's around my area and they all speak highly of it. Phonegap has recently came into the possession of Adobe so you can expect it to become a more highly supported/documented platform that you can create multi-platform apps from. Plus it meets your requirements

I'm avoiding PhoneGap myself at the minute because I want to get to grips with Obj-C and C# to  expand my knowledge of different programming languages but if I was trying to target as many platforms as possible, PhoneGap is top.